# Changing owner vs creating Share record via Share record or Group

Tags: apex, sharing, apex-sharing

Scenario :  Account and Contact both are private for external users.

A user (A) from community creates a new contact and an email is triggered to the contact for registration flow.

The registration flow opens up with a guest user profile and contact started registration and a portal user (B) is created.

Now when the new user (B) is created and when he logs in to `digital experience`, he is not able to modify his contact because the contact owner is user (A).

In this case there are few options,

1. update the contact owner to User (B)
2. create a group and share the user to that group (in that group only one user will be there).
3. create a share record `ContactShare` with userId as User (B) and Contact Id as the contact id, and ContactAccessLevel as 'Edit'

I am going for 3rd option, but not sure of the pitfalls in that. Also this needs to happen programmatically so option 1 seems impossible.

Comment: Do you want to keep the record accessible to both user A and B?

Comment: User A should have read access and user B should have read/write both. But logically the access should be revoked from User A and granted to User B.

Comment: Which community license are you using?

Comment: regardless of License type, seems to me the right sharing mechanism here is a Sharing Set.

Comment: also to OP, if it is a requirement that user (A) not have visibility to the Contact they created, you could use a simple auto-launched Flow running in System Context to change Ownership.

Comment: @rahulgawale, I am using Partner License, with custom profile.

Answer (score 1):

It can be simpler than all that, you should use a [Sharing Set](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5). The Access Grant would be:

- Object = Contact
- Access Determined By = User:Contact = Contact:Id
- Access Level = Read/Write

Comment: I see that profile selection is an option, if I dont specify a profile then will that work?

Comment: Sharing Sets are bound to Profiles. I suggest that you review documentation and explore in a sandbox to understand how this feature works.

Comment: This works, but as its dependent on Profile, the only drawback is that it that we cannot send this in a managed package, because the profiles may change in sponsors org.